# Outlook Web Application: удалилась картинка-фон из кода html e-mail

Tags: html, outlook

Може где галочку снять/поставить, а?
Пересылаю себе HTML-письмо - по дороге в OWA теряется линк на картинку-фон (линка не видать и в инспекторе). Mail.ru и Gmail в этом не замечены.

Comment: Некто пояснил мне, что background Outlook не поддерживает... :(

Comment: Может это вам поможет [Вёрстка html письма в Outlook](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667624/%D0%92%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-html-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-outlook)