# Вёрстка html письма в Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался, есть ли возможность сделать картинку фоном для письма в Outlook.
Такой пример не работает:

```
<body background="URL">
...
</body>
```

Необходимо корректно отображать в Outlook 2010 и owa (веб Outlook).
Верстка табличная, стили инлайновые.
Не пинайте, впервые сталкиваюсь.

Comment: По умолчанию Outlook блокирует изображения, принудительно его не заставишь их видеть, разве что поставить в настройках доверенность. Есть хороший фреймворк для верстки писем https://mjml.io/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь стилями, код может выглядеть примерно вот так...

```
<body style="background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CWTJs-bU4AAzCFU.jpg');"></body>
```

Приведённый код не будет работать для всех клиентов. Лучше воспользовался вот таким способом...

Добавте сразу после `<body>` таг:

```
<div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CWTJs-bU4AAzCFU.jpg" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CWTJs-bU4AAzCFU.jpg">
```

Далее ваш контент и перед закрытием `</body>` таг:

```
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите узнать больше о картинке в сообщение, пожалуйста посмотрите этот [ресурс](https://litmus.com/community/learning/25-understanding-background-images-in-email). Это на Английском, но браузер переведет.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что закомментированный блок это стиль Microsoft? Оно работает, не совсем очевидно для меня, правда. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Да, все правильно. Этот блок нужен для Microsoft Outlook клиента, более старые версии его. Это называеться [Vector Markup Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384217(v=vs.85).aspx). Извените по русски не знаю где найти.